# How to get sum of each element in two matrices of R

Tags: r, matrix, sum

I want to get sum of combination of each element of two matrices.

For example, 
combination of [ 2, 4, 6] and [3, 6, 9] to be [5, 7, 12,  8, 10, 15,  11, 13, 18].

I have only idea to get that result as

```
x<-rbind(c(2,4,9))
y<-rbind(c(3,6,9))
x+y[1]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5   7    12
x+y[2]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    8   10   15
x+y[3]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   11   13   18
```

I have 30 matrices, so elements will expand to 3^30 = 2.05891132 × 10^14 elements.

I believe it may exist a better way for doing it.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! I'm not native to English..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arun suggests, your question is hard to interpret.  But, is this what you mean?  (I presume you forgot to include 18 in your example.)

```
> a <- c(2,4,9)
> b <- c(3,6,9)
> sort(rowSums(expand.grid(a,b)))
[1]  5  7  8 10 11 12 13 15 18
```

Comment: No, not necessary, but the order depends on the grid expansion; hence: `rowSums(expand.grid(a,b))` gives `[1]  5  7 12  8 10 15 11 13 18`

Comment: True, but I wish it was ;-)

Comment: Thank you Andy! `rowSums(expand.grid(a,b))` is the best method for many matrices. I have product of all combinations of a element from each matrix by outer product and will merge result of sum and result of product to one table. So order of elements is vary important to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd throw out another solution using `outer`. Copying @Arun, here's some benchmarks:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)
REP <- function() { z1 <- rep(x, length(x)) + rep(y, each=length(y)) }
GRID <- function() { z2 <- rowSums(expand.grid(x,y)) }
OUTER <- function() { z3 <- c(outer(x,y,"+")) }
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(REP(), GRID(), OUTER(), replications = 10, order = "elapsed")

     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3 OUTER()           10    0.24    1.000      0.19     0.05         NA        NA
1   REP()           10    0.31    1.292      0.21     0.10         NA        NA
2  GRID()           10    2.10    8.750      1.57     0.44         NA        NA
```

Comment: @Arun, you are right. I need to wrap with `c` and I'll fix the missing `")`

Comment: Thanks for faster solution, but I think `outer` function works only for two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? It picks all combinations of a element from each matrix and returns there sum

```
> x <- c(2, 4, 9)
> y <- c(3, 6, 9)
> 
> a <- rep(x,length(y))
> b <- rep(y, each=length(x))
> 
> c <- a + b
> c <- c[order(c)]
> c
[1]  5  7  8 10 11 12 13 15 18
```

Comment: I can't upvote yet.. But I like Andy Barbour's expand.grid method. Neat indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `combn`.

```
sapply(a,function(x)combn(c(x,b),2,FUN=sum)[1:length(a)])
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    7   12
[2,]    8   10   15
[3,]   11   13   18
```